# Check To See A Match In MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form which has a textbox with an attribute called ref. once this is submitted, it updates on of my fields in the database. I have this code working and fine but what i need now is for it to check if the data entered into the textbox exists in the database and if it does, then it should notify the user to choose another reference. here is my code for the php end:

```
$ref = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['ref']);
$id = $_GET['public'];

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "*****", "******");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db('*****', $con);

$sql = "UPDATE public SET ref = '$ref' WHERE public_id = '$id'";

if (!mysql_query($sql, $con)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
    echo '<hr><h2>Reference Number Has Been Assigned Successfully</h2><hr>';
}
```

any ideas guys?

thanks

Comment: [Bobby-Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) much?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the number of rows affected:

```
$rowsAffected = mysql_affected_rows($con);
if($rowsAffected) {
    //something WAS changed!
}
else {
    //NOTHING was changed ... :-(
}
```

---

Also I would watch out for [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

You might want to use `mysqli` or `PDO`'s prepared queries for what you want to do.

---

### Based on OP's comment below:

```
...

if (!mysql_query($sql, $con)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
} else {

    $rowsAffected = mysql_affected_rows($con);
    if($rowsAffected) {
        echo '<hr><h2>Reference Number Has Been Assigned Successfully</h2><hr>';
    }
    else {
        //show some error message?
    }
    
}
```

Comment: how can i blend this code in to my update statement above? :S

Comment: it doesnt show no error message. it just submits the same data into the databasE?

Comment: @MohemaBurhan `$rowsAffected` is an integer. if the number is **not** `0` then it is successful, else then u should hit the else and your error message.

Comment: huh? im sorry im new to php so bear with me. my textbox contains some values which are randomly generated. these values are a combination of letters and numbers. i have copied your code and in the else section, i have put an echo statement. i have copied the same reference number i have in my database but to no avail. it still submits the same data without any errors showing up.

Comment: Why should there be an error? if a row was affected, then there should be **no** error!

Comment: i dont want two of the same figures in the database.

Comment: @MohemaBurhan then set the column as unique in MySQL, this is not a function of PHP, but of your database design.

Comment: im sure theres some sort of code that says if theres a match then do not execute code

Answer (score 0):

In this case First you run a select command to search for the record with particular reference number. If the result is eof , then run insert command. If not EOF then send a warning to the user saying reference number exist and choose another one.